# Do random forests use weak learners (like XGBoost) or fully grown trees?

Tags: random-forest, boosting, cart, ensemble-learning

So it sounds like boosting techniques (eg. XGBoost) uses weak learners (stumps) to gradually learn sequentially. This is not in dispute I hope.

However, with bagging techniques (eg. Random Forest) I'm not sure if it grows weak learners (like stumps) in parallel, or fully grown trees in parallel? Since the definition of "Ensemble modeling" is using many weak learners to form 1 powerful model, I'm leaning towards Random Forests using stumps, but I can be swayed the other direction as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Xgboost` can use deep or shallow trees (you can set a maximum tree depth). The default xgboost tree depth is 6; see [the `xgboost` documentation](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parameter.html#parameters-for-tree-booster).

Likewise, random forest can use deep or shallow trees for the same reason. For example, the implementation in [`sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) has no maximum depth by default, so the behavior is "nodes are expanded until all leaves are pure or until all leaves contain less than min_samples_split samples."

Comment: Perf thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The original motivation for random forests is to make decision trees less overfit, and in that sense fully grown trees are the expectation.  However, in practice I find that some pruning still provides a benefit.

Stumps are quite unlikely to be optimal though.  Unlike boosting, where each subsequent tree improves upon the current fit, bagging weak learners doesn't let them learn from each other.  Most likely you'll end up with lots of the stumps being exactly the same: their bags just aren't different enough from each other to choose different splits.

Comment: Good clarification on stumps being suboptimal. You prune your random forests? Thought pruning only applies if ur only using single decision trees?

Comment: @Katsu Anything that prevents a full tree can be called pruning. I had in mind "pre-pruning" methods: setting a maximum depth or number of leaves, or minimum number of samples per leaf or impurity improvement per split.

Comment: Gotcha prepruning def makes sense!